# Squeeking sound back of car caused by exhaust?

Tags: exhaust, squeaking

My car keeps making a squeaking sound at back. There is an exhaust pipe which if you shake it makes noise.

I'm wondering if its that the case, however i only notice the squeeking sound when going very slowly and also only on occasion i.e. not much.

Might it be the exhaust or are there other items(especially safety critical) I should be looking into?

I got someone to look at it and they didn't find anything besides the exhaust.  Would it be safe to say then that it is the exhaust?
Should placing a clamp on the exhaust remove the sound?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, suspension items and pipes.

Comment: @SolarMike  sorry mike, didnt write my thoughts clearly, have edited question.

Comment: You might as well put a clamp on the exhaust. If the sound doesn't stop, then it wasn't the exhaust :-)